# gcj compile to arm

Tags: android, arm, gcj, libgcj

I am trying to build micro libgcj for android ndk. I can get to build find but when I try to link libulibgcj.a I get invalid format error. I think it is because of gcj not compiling to arm. Two static libraries are built libgc.a and libulibgcj.a. I am able to link libgc.a which is all c code. Libulibgcj.a is a combo of c++ and java. So is there anyway to compile java code to arm as I have noticed there no armeabi-gcj in the android ndk bin folder?